# No stack overflow exploit on AARCH64/ARMv8?

Tags: reverse-engineering, arm64, exploit

This might be a dumb question but I would like to ask can stack overflow turns into a fully exploit in AARCH64/ARMV8?

So the function epilogue on ARMV8 is like:

```
0x5555555bf4 <main+128>       ldp    x29,  x30,  [sp], #64
0x5555555bf8 <main+132>       ret
```

However seems `ldp` cannot write to x30(LR) in ARMV8? Why is that and does that mean there is no way to write x30 solely relying on one buffer overflow on the stack? Also where is the documentation on the LR protection, i.e. what/which instructions can write LR and how can that be exploited?

In ARMV7/ARM32, stack overflow can overwrite lr since it still supports PUSH/POP, seems AARCH64/ARMV8 is very different. Can someone give me a good explanation regarding the exploit development on these two arch?

Comment: What makes you think x30 is "protected" in any way?

Comment: @Siguza I debugged it and found x30 not changed after ldp

Comment: Then chances are, the value on the stack simply matches the value that was already in the register. Or your debugger is messing with you.